# How to show all checked values in AJAX load checkbox group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

I've `checkbox` list that load by `ajax` and I want to show the checked value in page while user checking each checkbox. Please see below image.
[image]

Hear That country and City load from the `ajax` according to the parent selection. Here there are 4 cites are checked and I want to show those all selected city values below the check boxes.

I've used below jquery code but it doesn't work.

```
$("#cites input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
 var checkedc = $(this).val();
   $('#show_city').html(checkedc);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You have to use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

like this

```
$(document).on('change', '#cites input[type="checkbox"]',function () { //better use change event 
    if (this.checked) {// check if the checkbox is checked
        var checkedc = this.value;
        $('#show_city').html(checkedc);
    }
});
```

or

```
$('parentElementPresesntAtDOMready').on('click','#cites input[type="checkbox"]',function(){
   // code here
});
```

---

Updated After OP's comment

[.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

```
$(document).on('change', '#cites input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    var checkedc = $('#cites input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {//use map to create array of checked elements
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(); //than join array with comma to string
    $('#show_city').html(checkedc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This works some what because it don't load all cites that I checked. It is only show last checked city. Is is need any `append` method ?

Comment: @miuranga append will create problem as if uncheck the element how will remove it ? So Better use the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completing Tushar's answer so that you get all the checked cities :

```
$(document).on('change', '#cites input[type="checkbox"]',function () { //better use change event 
    var listChecked = "";
    if (this.checked) {// check if the checkbox is checked
        if (this.checked) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            listChecked = listChecked + value + ";";
        }
    }
    $('#show_city').html(listChecked);
});
```